# Rails 5: Post route doesn't work with root url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm currently adding a survey form to my homepage. The visitor then gets suggestions based on the input. I'm sending an ajax request to deliver the suggestions to the user.

Since the form is on my homepage, I need to create a `post` route for my `root url`.

My ajax code:

```
  $.ajax({
    data: 'impressions=' + impressions,
    dataType: 'script',
    type: 'post',
    url: "/pages/home"
  });
```

When I use `pages/home` in the `url` I get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/pages/home"):
```

When I just use `/` in the `url` I get the this error:

```
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"impressions"=>"278"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

It's somehow processing through the `RegistrationsController`

Those are my routes:

```
  root to: 'pages#home'
  # pages/home/:impressions not working
  post 'pages/home/:impressions' => 'pages#home'
```

PagesController home:

```
  def home
    @impressions = params[:impressions]
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`post 'pages/home/:impressions' => 'pages#home'`

to

`post 'pages/home' => 'pages#home'`